# Android emulator TTS data files?

Tags: android, android-emulator, text-to-speech

Where are android **emulator** TTS data files?
I want to test my App that would to install TTS files on target device.So I would to delete TTS files and install my data files on emulator and then test them.But I don't found any TTs file on emulator(on sdcard / svox),although I can "listen to an example" in settings screen for Text to Speech in emulator.